# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set with XSSFWorkbook

Tags: excel, spring-boot, spring, apache-poi

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo `.xlsx` de mi carpeta resources, pero cuando intento crear el XSSFWorkbook me da el siguiente error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:342)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:285)
    ...
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
    ...
```

El código que tengo actualmente simplemente hace esto:

```
public Object prueba() {
    
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/excels/test.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    String response = null;
    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is); <-- Here the error occurs
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
        response = row.getCell(9).getRawValue();
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Y en modo de depuración la variable `is` si tiene contenido

[image]

También agregué esto a mi pom.xml

```
<resource>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  <filtering>false</filtering>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
  </includes>
</resource>
```

Comment: Solo por descartar... ¿has probado a poner el fichero fuera de los resources a ver si lo lee bien? Es decir, que lo lea como un fichero externo, por ejemplo en /var o en /tmp

Comment: Este error lo tienes cuando ejecutas en el IDE o ejecutando la aplicación con el .jar.